# The Median of Practically Recreational Languages

Tags: code-golf, math, array

According to [TIO](https://tio.run/) there are two types of programming languages:

- Practical (seen in many corporate environments as a development standard).
- Recreational (if seen in a corporate environment, you're probably fired).

### Your Task

Mix together one language from each of these realms to achieve the simple goal of calculating the median of a list.  You will write a program (or function) in one language of each type.  The list will be composed entirely of integers, and will be fed as input to your first program.  The output of that program will then be fed as input to the second program.  For a valid answer, the output of the second language must always be the median of the list.  Both programs must be at least 1 byte in length, and both must have an output that differs from their input in at least one case (e.g., neither program may be a cat program).  If the list has an even number of elements, your program may output any value between the two elements of the list closest to the median (inclusive).  The list is guaranteed to contain at least one element, and consist entirely of integers.

## Test Cases

```
[1,2,3,4,5] = 3

[1,2,3,4,5,6] = 3-4

[-1,4,3,-2,0] = 0

[0,1,2,7,8,9] -> 2-7

[1,2,3,7,8,9] -> 3-7
```

### Scoring:

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), lowest sum of the byte-count of the two programs wins.

Comment: It looks like answers are just going to have one language do the work (probably with a built-in), while the other does something that just avoids the must-change restriction.

Comment: That is a problem.  I'm hoping for some more inventive answers though.

Comment: It's also not totally clear to me what counts as changing the input, given our defaults. For example, does it count if a function take a list and output its string representation? (Or do you really intend to enforce "program" and not allow functions?)

Comment: It does, as the output is not the same as the input.

Answer (score 7):

## [Python](https://docs.python.org/3/) + [Actually](https://github.com/Mego/Seriously), 6 + 1 = 7 bytes

```python
sorted
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzvzi/qCQ15X9BUWZeiUaaRrSuoY6JjrGOrpGOQaym5n8A)**

```python
║
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0wuKU3Myan8///R1In//0frGuqY6Bjr6BrpGMQCAA)**

The twist is that the Actually built-in for median (`║`) doesn't sort the list, hence it is perfectly combined with Python's `sorted()` built-in.

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly) + [Python](https://docs.python.org/),  <s>4 3</s>  2 + 3 = 5 bytes

-1 thanks to [Mr. Xcoder](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/59487/mr-xcoder) (`;0` -> `W` - I considered this but incorrectly disregarded it as an option)
-1 thanks to [Luis Mendo](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/36398/luis-mendo) (drop the `W` and change from `sum` to `int`)

Part 1, [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly) function:

```
Æṁ
```

A function which, given a list of integers will return their median.
e.g. `[-1,-9,-2,-8,0,-7]` yields `-4.5`.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9w28Odjf8Ptx@d9HDnjP//o3UNdXQtdXSNdHQtdAx0dM1jAQ)**

Part 2, [Python](https://docs.python.org/) function:

```
int
```

A function which given an integer or a floating point number returns an integer (dropping any fractional part).
e.g. `-4.5` yields `-4`.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPzOv5H9BEZDUSNPQNdEz1dT8/x8A)**

Comment: Would `W` work instead of `;0`?

Comment: Nope because Jelly represents a single item list as just the element

Comment: ...although come to think of it I suppose it depends what "The output of that program..." means here, hmm. Edit yes I think it can be just `W`.

Comment: Yeah `;0` was a replacement for `W` which I had decided would not be acceptable, but you are right - the function's output is a list and that's all that should matter.

Comment: I must admit you found a short nearly-no-op... +1

Comment: I think you can drop `W` from Jelly and use `int` in Python

Comment: @LuisMendo "both must have an output that differs from their input in at least one case" - The output from the Jelly function would be an integer. Maybe we can drop the `W` and say the Jelly code is a full program so it prints a string? I dunno though. Edit - oh I see, the output wont always be an integer!

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly) + [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), <s>5</s> 4 + 3 = 7 bytes

```
ÆṁṾṚ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASgA1/9qZWxsef//w4bhuYHhub7huZr/xpPDh/9bMTAsMjAsMzAsNDAsNTBd)

*-1 byte* thanks to *Jonathan Allan*

A monadic chain that takes a list and returns (is that the right terminology?) the stdin for the bash program.

```bash
rev
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/vyi17P9/A2MA)

### Explanation

```bash
ÆṁṾṚ
  Ṿ   String representation
Æṁ    of the median
   Ṛ  reversed
```

Comment: @JonathanAllan fixed... even if the challenge says it was OK :P

Comment: Yes that change is a result of my question under the OP.

Comment: I believe you can do `ÆṁṾṚ`for this.

Comment: @JonathanAllan Thanks. As totallyhuman said, Jelly is a game of atom hide and programmer seek.

Answer (score 1):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL) + [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 1 + 19 = 20 bytes

```r
S
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/P/j/fwA)

`S` reads in input as a matrix `[a_1, a_2, ..., a_n]` and then sorts it. Then the program terminates, printing the values as `b_1 b_2 ... b_n`, which is then read by R's `scan()` as a vector. The R program then computes the median and prints it out.

```r
cat(median(scan()))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/PzmxRCM3NSUzMU@jOBlIaGpq/v8PAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org) + [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 11 + 10 = 21 bytes

```javascript
n=>n.sort()
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@z/P1i5Przi/qERD839yfl5xfk6qXk5@ukaaRrSuoY6JjrGOrpGOQaym5n8A)

```javascript
.O@R/lQ2_B
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/X8/fIUg/J9Ao3un//2gFXUMdBV0jHQUDHQVjHQUThVgA)

### How the Pyth code works

```
.O@R/lQ2_B ~ Full program.

        _B ~ Bifurcate with reverse; Yields [Input, Reverse(Input)]
    /lQ2   ~ The length of the input divided by two, and floored.
  @R       ~ For each in ^^, get the element at index ^.
.O         ~ Average (arithmetic mean).
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Actually](https://github.com/Mego/Seriously) and [Python](https://docs.python.org/3/), 1 + 3 = 4 bytes

### Actually, 1 byte

```
║
```

Full program that computes the median, possibly with a decimal part. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0wuKU3Myan8///R1In//0cb6BjqGOmY61joWMYCAA)

### Python, 3 bytes

```
int
```

Defines a function that rounds towards zero. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPzOv5H9BEZDUSNPQNdEz1dT8/x8A)